# Automatically open files on IntelliJ/WebStorm startup

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I noticed newer versions of the JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ/WebStorm 2020.x) will *automatically* open the file `README.md` if one exists in the project root whenever opening a new folder/project for the first time (i.e. *no* previous `.idea/` exists).

Is it possible to specify/customize the files that are opened? For example I would like it to also **always** automatically open `package.json`, `Cargo.toml`, and `build.gradle` + `app/build.gradle` if they exist in a project.

Comment: I am not quite sure but I think that that thing is only with README.md files but I guess that you can change that through the configuration files.

Comment: It does look like it is hardcoded to look for `README.md` (exact spelling/capitalization). And yes, I'm looking for the location where it is specified and if it's user editable.

Comment: There is no such option to change the file. Feel free to file a request at [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).